# Splitting field and Galois group of $(x^5-1)(x^2+1)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, splitting-field

Consider $p(x) = (x^5-1)(x^2+1)$. Then, its splitting field is $\mathbb{Q}(e^{\frac{2\pi i}{5}}, i)$.

Thus, $f\in \text{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(e^{\frac{2\pi i}{5}}, i)/\mathbb{Q})$ maps $\omega = e^{\frac{2\pi i}{5}}$ to any of $\omega^k$ for $k=1,...,4$ and $i$ to $\pm i$.

In that way, I can conclude that $|\text{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(e^{\frac{2\pi i}{5}}, i)/\mathbb{Q})|= 4 \cdot 2 = 8$.

Now, how do I know which of the groups of order $8$ it is? It might be $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_4$ because of element orders but I am not sure.

Comment: There's no element of order $8$ so it's certainly not cyclic, is there an element of order $4$? Sure, so it's also not $(\Bbb Z/2)^3$. The question is then whether or not $\Bbb Z/2 \cong \operatorname{Gal}(\Bbb Q(i)/\Bbb Q)$ acts non-trivially as automorphisms on $\Bbb Z/4 \cong \operatorname{Gal}(\Bbb Q(\zeta_5)/\Bbb Q)$, i.e. that whether or not the Galois group of the big extension is a non-trivial semi-direct product of the Galois groups of the smaller extensions over $\Bbb Q$, or is simply the direct product. You can do this by checking whether $\Bbb Q(\zeta_5) \cap \Bbb Q(i) = \Bbb Q$.

Comment: The splitting field is equivalent to $\mathbb{Q}(e^{\pi i/10})$ i.e. the cyclotomic extension generated by a primitive 20th root of 1, therefore its Galois group over $\mathbb{Q}$ is abelian.

Comment: There are infinitely many rational numbers, let alone elements of the splitting field, so the tag [tag:finite-fields] is misplaced here. Anyway, Daniel Schepler's comment is the key. More generally, adjoining various roots of unity to the rationals always gives you a cyclotomic field with a known, easy to describe Galois group. Your field is $\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_{20})$ so the Galois group is $\Bbb{Z}_{20}^*$, which is, indeed isomorphic to $C_2\times C_4$.

Comment: How do you know that my extension is $\mathbb{Q}(e^{\frac{\pi i}{10}})$? @DanielSchepler

Comment: $i / e^{2\pi i/5} = e^{\pi i/10}$ so $\mathbb{Q}(e^{\pi i/10}) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(e^{2\pi i/5}, i)$; and conversely, both $i$ and $e^{2\pi i/5} \in \mathbb{Q}(e^{\pi i/10})$ so $\mathbb{Q}(e^{2\pi i/5}, i) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(e^{\pi i/10})$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have found all the elements of the Galois group. This means it wont be too hard to find a structure description of the group by looking at how the elements interact.

An important element is the complex conjugation automorphism. Call it $\tau$. $\tau$ maps $i$ to $-i$ and maps $\omega$ to $\omega^{-1} = \omega^{4}$ Let's consider how $\tau$ interacts with the maps $\sigma_k$ defined by $\sigma_k \omega = \omega^k$, $\sigma_k i = i$.

- $\sigma_k \tau (\omega) = \sigma_k (\omega^{-1}) = \omega^{-k}$
- $\sigma_k \tau (i) = \sigma_k (-i) = -i$
- $\tau \sigma_k (\omega) = \tau (\omega^k) = \omega^{-k}$
- $\tau \sigma_k (i) = \tau (i) = -i$

So we have seen that $\tau$ commutes with each $\sigma_k$.

This tells us that $G$ is an inner direct product of $\langle \tau \rangle$ of order 2 with $\langle \sigma_1 \rangle$ of order 4. Thus $$G = C_2 \times C_4.$$

Comment: But I want to add the comment that noticing we have 20th roots of unity since your field is a compositum of two cyclotomic fields is a much more elegant solution.